# Drawbacks of a Tip jet helicopter

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft

A Tip Jet helicopter offers some advantages, i.e. eliminates transmission, torque is lower, etc.
Engineers experimented with this design in 1950s, but remains marginal at best.

**What are the drawbacks of tip jets?**

Comment: This is an engineering question rather than a physics question. I'd be tempted to ask on the [Aviation Stack Exchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) as they're generally pretty good at answering questions about aircraft design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the physics of tip jets are such that as a propulsive means, they are very thermodynamically inefficient which means most of the helicopter's payload consists of fuel and not cargo or passengers. Trading payload off against fuel load results in unacceptably short range for tip jets.

Furthermore, the aerodynamics of a "dead" (i.e., flamed out) tip jet rotor system are such as to severely interfere with autorotation in the event of fuel exhaustion or mechanical failure. This means that a tip jet flameout is extremely difficult for the pilot to safely manage without making a hard landing.